# Set class property inside function

Tags: node.js

I know how to set class property inside it: `this.property = 1`.

But what should I do if it's inside a function?
Example:

```
class Test = {
    constructor(){
        var request = require('request');
        request(options, function(err, res, body){
            // Here I want to set Test property
            // Something like this.property = 1 or 
            // Test.property = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not great with js so this isn't probably the best solution, but I'm pretty sure you could do something like `const self = this;` outside your anonymous function, then set it using `self.property = 1;` while inside the function.

Comment: @Addison yeah, it works, like `Test.property = 1;` also. Maybe somebody explains difference and what is better

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve then. `Test.property` and `this.property` are apples and oranges. Do you want to set instance or static property?

Comment: I just found this page explaining various workarounds for this issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this. It's definitely worth looking at. From reading that section, it looks like using strict mode also fixes this issue (although I still like @estus's answer the best, as it looks nicer and doesn't rely on knowing where the js will run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what arrow functions are for, they provide lexical this in function scope.

```
request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    this.property = 1
})
```

Also, side effects in class constructor is an antipattern, especially asynchronous ones.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Exactly what I looked for. About asynchronous functions inside constructor. What should I do if I want to make request after calling `new Test()`?

Comment: I usually have explicit class method like `fetch` and call it explicitly. Even if this is done in constructor, it's a good practice to have callback parameter in constructor, so it's possible to notify the code outside the class that initialization was completed. But when you switch from callbacks to promises (I'd recommend to do that ASAP) it becomes evident that separate `fetch` method works better.

Comment: Thanks again. You've definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

"this", is a keyword. It refers to the object. "this.someProperty", means the concerned object's someProperty property.

Test is the class name. Test.property is simply wrong way to address an object's property.

As noted above, the right way to address the property from within a function is to use an arrow function.

```
class Test = {
  constructor(){
    var request = require('request');
    request(options, (err, res, body)=>{
        this.property = 1
    })
  }
}

var aTest = new Test();  // a Test object
var anotherTest = new Test(); // another Test object

// Change the property value of the objects
aTest.property = 5
anotherTest.property = 10
```